# Openstack SDK, create new server only IPV4

Tags: python, cloud, openstack

```
conn: Connection = create_connection()

nics = [{'net-id': '`net_id`', 'subnet-id': '`subnet_id`'}]

params = {
    'name': 'Instance_app_2',
    'networks': [{'uuid': 'net_id'}],
    'nics': nics,
    'security_groups': [{'name': 'GroupName'}],
    'user_data': create_user_data(), # encoded user_data
    'flavor_id': '`flavor_id`'
    'image_id': '`image_id`',
    'ipv6_address_mode': None,
    'ipv6_ra_mode': None,
}

server = conn.compute.create_server(**params)
```

I run the code and create a server have both IPv4 and IPv6.
How can I create a new server with only IPv4 ? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `ipv6_address_mode` and `ipv6_ra_mode` are used by `network.create_subnet` rather than `compute.create_server` method, and their `Valid values are: 'dhcpv6-stateful', 'dhcpv6-stateless', or 'slaac'`.

Secondly, the `networks` parameter `Mutually exclusive with the nics parameter` in `create_server` method.

Lastly, in your case `create a server have both IPv4 and IPv6`, I guess that you had already defined the `ipv6_address_scope` in net_id or `ipv6_*_mode` in subnet_id, so it would auto create ipv6 address.

Try to create a **port_id** which *port only with ipv4 address*, and just use `'nics': port_id,` to `create_server`.

see also: https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html